# Can I re-project an LAS file in LidR

Tags: r, lidr

I am working with 2 adjacent 2014 LAS dataset provided in 2 projections: [image]

However, when I type espg(las) my returned answer is  0

If I type summary(las) my coord.Ref.: NA

[image]

I wish to re-project both of these to NAD83/UTM18 and process them together through LiDR. I am unclear if this is possible to do in LiDR? How best to proceed? I have 1000 1km tiles to deal with.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove screenshoot of text to include actual text.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign a CRS to your LAS object with `epsg()<-`

```r
epsg(las) <- 12345
```

You can re-project with `st_transform()` but this function is suboptimal in its current implementation. It actually transforms the `LAS` into a `MULTIPOINT`, uses `sf::st_transform()` and updates back the `LAS` object. I recommend to use `las2las` from `LAStools` for this kind of LAS file processing tasks but for small dataset `st_transform` may be convenient.

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
las
#> class        : LAS (v1.2 format 1)
#> memory       : 6.2 Mb 
#> extent       : 684766.4, 684993.3, 5017773, 5018007 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : NAD83 / UTM zone 17N  
#> area         : 53112.69 m²
#> points       : 81.6 thousand points
#> density      : 1.54 points/m²
las2 = st_transform(las, st_crs(26918))
las2
#> class        : LAS (v1.2 format 1)
#> memory       : 6.2 Mb 
#> extent       : 214261.7, 214504.9, 5021517, 5021767 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : NAD83 / UTM zone 17N 
#> area         : 53174.62 m²
#> points       : 81.6 thousand points
#> density      : 1.53 points/m²
```

---

**Note** - before `lidR 3.0.4` the function is a little bit buggy.
If you check `las2` you will see it is no longer strictly compliant to the specifications. It was fixed in `lidR 3.0.4`.

```r
las_check(las2)
```

Comment: Is it possible, that this does not work anymore? I just tried it and got an error like this:  `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :   cannot find inherited method for function 'spTransform' for signature '"LAS", "CRS"` (translated from German)

Comment: use st_transform. See my edited anwser

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!

Comment: are there any updates on this, or is the "suboptimal" st_transform() still the way to go? las2las by LAStools doesn't know the EPSG codes I'm working with, therefore unfortunately I can't use it for the projection of my (rather large) dataset. So I'll go with retiling and st_transform() on each tile.

Comment: actually, sf::st_transform results in an error for me: `Error in UseMethod("st_transform"): not applicable method 'st_transform' applied to object of class "c('LAS', 'Spatial')"`.

Comment: you are using a version of lidR that is more than 1 year old